# Html5 notifications click event after refresh is not working

Tags: javascript, html, events, notifications

I have the following test html with javascript, where the main interest is about notifications :

```
<head>
    <title>Test Notifications</title>

</head>
<body>


    <div >
        <button  style="margin: 0;position: absolute;top: 50%;left: 50%;-ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);transform: translate(-50%, -50%);" 
                 onclick="askPermissionsAndSendNotification();"  >Send Notification</button>

    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript"   >
        function askPermissionsAndSendNotification() {

            if (!window.Notification) {
                return false;
            } else {
                if (Notification.permission === 'default') {
                    Notification.requestPermission(function (p) {
                        if (p !== 'denied') {
                            sendNotification();
                        }
                    })
                } else {
                    sendNotification();
                }
            }
        }

        function sendNotification() {
            let title = "Test notification";
            let message = "Test notification content";
            let  myNotification = new Notification(title, {
                body: message
            });
            myNotification.addEventListener('click', function () {
                window.open("https://stackoverflow.com/","_blank");
            });
        }
    </script>

</body>
```

Is a simple notification , we send it by clicking on the button , and will open a new tab with an url . Everything works perfect until refresh.

If you have a notification not closed, if you refresh the page ,whatever will be code in your click event, the notification will open a new page with your website base url . I assume the listener is destroyed on page refresh, probably this is the default behaviour . Can something be done to have the original notification onclick action called after a page refresh if notification is created before the refresh ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notifications in the browser are *non-persistent* which causes them to stop working whenever you close your tab. You'll need to move your logic to a Service Worker to be able to use *persistent* notifications. Service Workers will run regardless of opened or closed tabs after they've been installed.

First start of by registering your Service Worker. Then modify the  `sendNotification` function. We want to let the function send a message to the Service Worker with the information that your notification needs, instead of creating a `Notification` ourselfs, then the worker will be in charge of creating the notification.

Messages can be sent to a Service Worker with the [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorker/postMessage) method of the current registered worker. You can also send the URL you want the user to redirect to when clicking.

```js
// app.js
navigator.serviceWorker.register('serviceworker.js');

async function sendNotification() {
  let title = "Test notification";
  let message = "Test notification content";
  const url = "https://stackoverflow.com/";

  // Wait until the Service Worker ready.
  const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.ready;

  // Send a message over to the worker.
  registration.active.postMessage({
    title,
    message,
    url
  })
}
```

On the Service Worker side you'll want first want to be able to receive any incoming message we send from the client. Listen for the `message` event and handle your received data from there. The Service Worker registration has a built in method called [`showNotification`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/showNotification) which does exactly the same as `new Notification()`. Pass your data to the method.

Then listen for the `notificationclick` event. Here you can handle whatever needs to happen when the user clicks the notification. From here you can access the `url` and open a new browser window with the [`openWindow()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clients/openWindow) method of the `Clients` interface.

```js
// serviceworker.js
addEventListener('message', ({ data }) => {
  // Deconstruct received data.
  const {
    title,
    message,
    url
  } = data;

  // Show notification with the received data.
  registration.showNotification(title, {
    body: message,
    data: {
      url
    }
  });
})

addEventListener('notificationclick', (event) => {
  event.notification.close();

  const { url } = event.notification.data;
  const openPage = clients.openWindow(url);
  event.waitUntil(openPage);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can save the notification inside local storage.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem

```
localStorage.setItem("notification", JSON.stringify({title,message}));
```

And later on inside an IIFE get the item that you want https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE.

```
(() => {
    const item = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('notification'));
    // Your logic below...
})();
```

Now you also need something to differentiate which item you want to save to local storage, because if you use the setItem above, every time you push a notification it will be pushed to storage.

Comment: The Notification click handling needs to work *after* the tab has been closed. This will only run when the page is *reopened*.